# Any way with Exposed to do an ON UPDATE in a table declaration?

Tags: kotlin-exposed

I want to update a time stamp similar to MySQLs "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Is there anyway to do this when declaring a table in Exposed?

Comment: No, this syntax is not supported yet.

Comment: I also notice that Postgres does not have that feature natively, so I'm not sure it can be done in a lowest common denominator sort of way?

Comment: You can try to use `clientDefault{ DateTime.now() }` on non-null column and skip that column in table updates. Exposed should fill that value on every update/insert.